# How to check in Python's User-Defined Functions weather a list[ ] passed to it contains only integers?

Tags: python, list, function, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to see if a list contains integers:

```
def fun(a):
    if a[:] == int:
        print('Sum of elements', sum(a))
        print('Minimum number ', min(a))
        print('Maximum number ', max(a))
        print('Length of elements', len(a))
    else:
        print('Give integers list only')

list = [1,2,3,4,5,'hi']
fun(list)
```

Output:

```
**Output :** *Give integers list only*
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check type item by item. Replace `if a[:]==int:` with

```
if all(isinstance(n, int) for n in a):
    ...
```

in your definition.

Comment: Yup , it works in my functions . Thanks for your kind help .

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through it and use
`is_integer()`
If at any point it fails then return an error

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(a):
    for value in a:
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            print('Give integers list only')
            break 
    else:
        print('Sum of elements', sum(a))
        print('Minimum number ', min(a))
        print('Maximum number ', max(a))
        print('Length of elements', len(a))
```